# Running Spark jobs with Marathon

Tags: java, apache-spark, mesos, marathon

I've got a Marathon job running for the following:

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.mesos.MesosClusterDispatcher
```

However, following that I'd like to now be able to run individual Spark jobs as separate Marathon jobs with the command:

```
./bin/spark-submit ....
```

My question is:
how can I call spark-submit from a Mesos executor of the binaries are not installed on it? 
(Note: I'm aware that http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#connecting-spark-to-mesos also recommends installing Spark on all the Mesos slaves, but is that the only option?)

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following command:

```
/opt/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master mesos://127.0.0.1:31258 --deploy-mode cluster --supervise --executor-memory 2G --total-executor-cores 1 /opt/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.1.0.jar 1000
```